# Why MySQL hangs on this simple SELECT @nb, @id_start query?

Tags: mysql

I'm running a SQL script on a table with more than 80M+ rows.
I'm using a procedure to process batches of rows and I'm running it with a call to the mysql CLI client.

This procedure uses this simple `SELECT @nb, @id_start` query to output the progress.

I found out that the procedure stops progressing at some point.

Adminer shows this line:

| Command | Time | State | Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Query | 28370 | Sending to client | SELECT @nb, @id_start |

=> My understanding is that this query has been running for 28370 seconds.

The SQL file I'm executing with the mysql CLI client is:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `LoopProcedure`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE LoopProcedure()
BEGIN
    SET @id_start := 24978724;
    
    SELECT @id_start := `cursor`
    FROM `temporary`
    WHERE `id` = 1;
    
    SET @nb := 0;
    loop_label: LOOP
        -- Select the max within the 1000 first rows
        SELECT @id_end := MAX(`emailId`)
        FROM (
            SELECT `emailId`
            FROM `BuyPacker_Email`
            WHERE `emailId` > @id_start
            ORDER BY `emailId`
            LIMIT 100
        ) as t;

        -- No more line found
        IF @id_end IS NULL OR @id_end = @id_start THEN
            LEAVE loop_label;
        END IF;
        -- Increment the counter
        SET @nb := (@nb + 100);

        -- Update these rows
        UPDATE `crm_contact`, `BuyPacker_Email`
        SET `crm_contact`.`email_status` = "VALID_EVENT"
        WHERE (`crm_contact`.`email_status` IN ("VALID", "NOT_VALID", "UNVERIFIED", "INVALID_SMTP") OR `crm_contact`.`email_status` IS NULL)
          AND `BuyPacker_Email`. `emailId` > @id_start 
          AND `BuyPacker_Email`. `emailId` <= @id_end 
          AND (`BuyPacker_Email`. `emailClick` IS NOT NULL OR `BuyPacker_Email`. `emailOpen` IS NOT NULL)
          AND `crm_contact`.`email` = `BuyPacker_Email`. `emailEmail`;
          
        UPDATE `email_list_recipient`, `BuyPacker_Email`
        SET `email_list_recipient`.`email_status` = "VALID_EVENT"
        WHERE `email_list_recipient`.`email_status` IN ("VALID", "NOT_VALID", "UNVERIFIED", "INVALID_SMTP")
          AND `BuyPacker_Email`. `emailId` > @id_start 
          AND `BuyPacker_Email`. `emailId` <= @id_end 
          AND (`BuyPacker_Email`. `emailClick` IS NOT NULL OR `BuyPacker_Email`. `emailOpen` IS NOT NULL)
          AND `BuyPacker_Email`. `emailEmail` COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci = `email_list_recipient`.`email`;

        UPDATE `temporary`
        SET `cursor` = @id_start
        WHERE `id` = 1;

        -- Moving forward the cursor
        SET @id_start := @id_end;
        -- Output the progress
        SELECT @nb, @id_start;
        -- Cut some slack to the server to execute other statements
        DO SLEEP(0.2);

    END LOOP;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL LoopProcedure();

DROP PROCEDURE `LoopProcedure`;
```

My setup is:

- The MySQL server is a Azure Database for MySQL Single Server
- The MySQL CLI client is running on an Azure Container Instance
- Both are within the same VNet

I expect this query to be always super fast, I don't understand why MySQL spends so much time on it.

Processing resumes if I kill this connection from Adminer and start a fresh MySQL CLI client command.